# Is it possible to combine two properties of an object of data in Ag Grid while exporting to excel

Tags: excel, ag-grid

I have a data like this for the grid

```
[
    {
       a: 123.0,
       delta: 2
    },
    {
       a: 46,
       delta: -5.1
    }
]
```

I wanted to show this information in excel as in the below screenshot in a single cell

[image]

For Ag grid browser rendering, I am using `cellRenderer` which helped me to render as I want but could not find any option for excel export.

Answer (score 0):

use below code in `excelStyles`

```
{
  id: 'twoDecimalPlaces',
  numberFormat: {
  format: '[Green]0.00% ▲;[Red] 0.00% ▼',
  },
},
```

here is the working [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/T8DEJo50JP4D8Gps?open=main.js).